# Why do I get the wrong outputs for values of webelements with my code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the last upload time for each folder at this webpage: https://www.evaschulze-aufgabenpool.de/index.php/s/smwP6ygck2SXRtF?path=%2FKlasse12

I'm using python and selenium and tried multiple ways of searching (find by xpath, by class name...) but I either get an error message ("no such element found") or the same value for all folders.
What seems to be the problem here and how can I resolve it?

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.evaschulze-aufgabenpool.de/index.php/s/smwP6ygck2SXRtF?path=%2FKlasse12"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

sleep(3)
lenOfPage = driver.execute_script(
    "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return 
lenOfPage;")
match = False
while not match:
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    sleep(3)
    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var 
lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    if lastCount == lenOfPage:
        match = True

data = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
data = data.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")

for element in data:
    name = element.get_attribute("data-file")
    date = element.find_element_by_xpath("//td[4]/span[1]").get_attribute("data-original-title")
    if name is not None:
        print(name, ", ", date)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

`//` Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection *no matter where they are* So it selected every iteration the first date in table.

### So how to fix that?

Prepend the `.` expression to select the current node:

```
date = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[4]/span[1]").get_attribute("data-original-title")
```

Or delete the `//` expression, cause element is the current node:

```
date = element.find_element_by_xpath("td[4]/span[1]").get_attribute("data-original-title")
```

**Pay attention that this will cause an error, so also change the following**
Slice the first and the last row of the table:

```
for element in data[1:-1]:
```

**Complete code**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.evaschulze-aufgabenpool.de/index.php/s/smwP6ygck2SXRtF?path=%2FKlasse12"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

sleep(3)
lenOfPage = driver.execute_script(
    "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
match = False
while not match:
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    sleep(3)
    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    if lastCount == lenOfPage:
        match = True

data = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
data = data.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")


for element in data[1:-1]:
    name = element.get_attribute("data-file")
    date = element.find_element_by_xpath("td[4]/span[1]").get_attribute("data-original-title")
    print(name, ", ", date)

driver.quit()
print(name, ", ", date)
```

**Output**

```
GK Antike Welt Lägel ,  8. Januar 2021 17:53
GK Astronomie Siewert ,  8. Januar 2021 16:47
GK Bio 1 Grüninger ,  10. Januar 2021 10:49
GK Bio 2 Fr ,  8. Januar 2021 09:43
GK Bio 3 Fr ,  9. Januar 2021 23:48
GK Bio 4 BöC ,  10. Januar 2021 00:00
GK Ch Pt ,  10. Januar 2021 19:10
```